# SMS messages non ASCII characters encoding

Tags: character-encoding, sms

I have a Nokia N900 phone, and when sending an SMS, the widget displays the number of characters left in the message (and the number of actual short messages needed to send the whole message).

I live in France, where I noticed the following odd thing when writing messages with non-ASCII characters:

- some non-ASCII chars are encoded on one char/byte , e.g. "é", "è", "à", "ù"
- the presence of some non-ASCII chars such as "ç", "ê", "ô" consumes a fixed amount of 90 char/bytes + 1 byte per character
- the presence of a second "ç", "ê" etc. only consumes 1 additional byte.

So I'm wondering how the messages are encoded, because I can't see the above scheme matching the traditional encodings I know (iso-8859-1, UTF-8, UTF-16...).

Comment: That is interesting.  I recently did some testing on an iPhone and an HTC EVO 4G, both U.S. phones.  Their software immediately switched to UCS-2 (fixed 16-bit-per-character encoding) when I entered non [GSM-03.38 7-bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38#GSM_7_bit_default_alphabet_and_extension_table_of_3GPP_TS_23.038_.2F_GSM_03.38) characters like í, even though that character can be encoded as two 7-bit GSM 03.38 characters.  In my tests, the phone did not give me that option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS#Message_size

Depend on the encoding, SMS can send 160/140/70 characters. If any of the non-ASCII chars are used, the entire message would have to be encoded in UTF-16, hence the "consumption" you experienced.

Comment: Close, but the above should read "If any of the non-GSM-7 chars used, the entire message would have to be encoded in UCS-2 [..]"

Answer (score 8):

@Vicky and @timdream are right, except that I believe it's technically [UCS-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCS-2) and not UTF-16 that the phone sometimes uses, which has a fixed 16-bit size per character.  UTF-16 uses a variable width of two or four bytes per character, depending on the character being encoded.  [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCS-2) explains this in detail.  UCS-2 strictly takes the message down to 70 characters at most (160 bytes).  Although [the Unicode Consortium's description of UCS-2](http://unicode.org/faq/basic_q.html#14) is a bit confusing, a handful of sites around the web dealing with SMS confirm that Wikipedia is right.

Comment: My understanding is that UTF-16 uses a variable width of 2 or 4 bytes per character (1 or 2 16bit codes).

Comment: Thank you, @gurneyalex.  I have corrected that in my comment above.

Answer (score 5):

You already have the answer from @timdream, but just an additional point that some of the extended characters you mention are included in the GSM 7-bit alphabet as single characters, some are encoded in GSM 7-bit through an additional escape character (so two bytes to represent that character) and some can't be encoded at all in GSM 7-bit and need to be encoded as UTF-16 instead.

The full alphabet definition is here:
http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/ETSI/GSM0338.TXT

Note the particular peculiarity with c-cedilla - from that file,

> The ETSI GSM 03.38 specification shows an uppercase C-cedilla
>   glyph at 0x09. This may be the result of limited display
>   capabilities for handling characters with descenders. However,
>   the
>   language coverage intent is clearly for the lowercase
>   c-cedilla, as shown
>   in the mapping below. The mapping for uppercase C-cedilla is
>   shown
>   in a commented line in the mapping table.

Some devices encode both upper and lower case c-cedilla as the same encoded character (0x09).