# How to count characters in an textarea with some characters counting as double ? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I would like to count the characters of a textarea field but some characters like "é, è, €, ..." counting for two. I have this special need for sending SMS plateform and SMS are limited to 160 characters but some count as double.

I've found many solutions on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371089/count-characters-in-textarea)  about counting characters but none with specific counting.

I'd like a Javascript (vanilla or JQuery) solution please.

Thank you !

Comment: Which characters should be counted as 2 characters? What's the logic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SMS messages non ASCII characters encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103990) and [Count characters/sms using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705185) and [SMS Character Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038234) and [international Count sms characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454910)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('keyup','textarea',function() {
    var all_same_char_counts = {};
    var duplicate_characterCount = 0;

    var source = $(this).val();
    var splittedSource = source.trim().replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').split(' ');
               
   jQuery.each(splittedSource, function(key,value) {
       if (!all_same_char_counts.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
            all_same_char_counts[value] = 1;
       } else {
           all_same_char_counts[value]++;
       }
    });
    jQuery('#the-duplicate-char-count').html(JSON.stringify(all_same_char_counts));
    //console.log(all_same_char_counts);

                
    Object.keys(all_same_char_counts).forEach(function(key) {
        duplicate_characterCount = duplicate_characterCount+all_same_char_counts[key];
                    
   });
   //console.log(duplicate_characterCount);

<!-- All characters count  -->
                var characterCount = source.length,
                    current = $('#current'),
                    maximum = $('#maximum'),
                    theCount = $('#the-count');
                
                current.text(characterCount);
            
                /*This isn't entirely necessary, just playin around*/
                if (characterCount < 70) {
                    current.css('color', '#666');
                }
                if (characterCount > 70 && characterCount < 90) {
                    current.css('color', '#6d5555');
                }
                if (characterCount > 90 && characterCount < 100) {
                    current.css('color', '#793535');
                }
                if (characterCount > 100 && characterCount < 120) {
                    current.css('color', '#841c1c');
                }
                if (characterCount > 120 && characterCount < 139) {
                    current.css('color', '#8f0001');
                }
                
                if (characterCount >= 140) {
                    maximum.css('color', '#8f0001');
                    current.css('color', '#8f0001');
                    theCount.css('font-weight','bold');
                } else {
                    maximum.css('color','#666');
                    theCount.css('font-weight','normal');
                }       
            });
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,700,300italic);
            *, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: border-box; }
            html { font-size: 100%;  }
            body { 
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            background: #d0e6ef; 
            color: #666;
            }
            .wrapper {
            max-width: 75%;
            margin: auto;
            }
            h1 { 
            color: #555; 
            margin: 3rem 0 1rem 0; 
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            }
            textarea {
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 100px;
            resize: none;
            border-radius: 8px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 0.5rem;
            color: #666;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.25rem #ddd;
            }
            textarea:focus {
                outline: none;
                border: 1px solid darken(#ddd, 5%);
                box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.5rem darken(#ddd, 5%);
            }
            textarea[placeholder] { 
                font-style: italic;
                font-size: 0.875rem;
            }
            #the-count {
            float: right;
            padding: 0.1rem 0 0 0;
            font-size: 0.875rem;
            }
            #the-duplicate-char-count{
                font-weight: bold;
                color:brown
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
            <h1>Displaying The Character Count of a Textarea</h1>
            <textarea name="the-textarea" id="the-textarea" maxlength="300" placeholder="Start Typin..."autofocus></textarea>
            <div id="the-count">
                <span id="current">0</span>
                <span id="maximum">/ 300</span>
            </div>
            <div id="the-duplicate-char-count"></div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Now I have updated my answer so you can count all characters and also count all duplicate words so now you can update the rest of the scrip accordingly.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't resolve my issue, the solution you share just count characters, there is not specific count for specific characters !

Comment: *"some characters like "é, è, €, ..." should be counted as two"*

Comment: Now I have updated my answer so you can get all duplicate characters